# AlarmManager sends intent with empty Bundle in Android N

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-7.0-nougat

I am scheduling 2 alarms for an Event. First in one hour before and the second in the Event time.
It works in Android M and lower. 
**In Android N the Bundle(extras) comes empty.**

This is how I create an intent

```java
public static Intent createEventIntent(final Context context, final Event event) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ALARM_TYPE, EXTRA_EVENT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_EVENT, event);
    return intent;
}
```

Event implements Serializable.

Then, I create a pending Intent

```java
final int broadCastId = event.hashCode();
final int broadCastId2 = broadCastId - 1; //to ensure 2 alarms
final PendingIntent alarmIntent =
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, broadCastId, intent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
final PendingIntent alarmIntentOneHourBefore =
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, broadCastId2, intent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then I schedule the alarms:

```java
mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
... 
mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendarOneHourBefore.getTimeInMillis(),
            alarmIntentOneHourBefore);
```

In the method onReceive, the extras are null:

```java
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    final String type = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ALARM_TYPE); // null in 7.0
}
```

This is happening only in Android N.

What am I missing?

I have tried:

- Event implements parcelable and then send a parcelable.
- Create a Bundle and add the extras to the Bundle.
- Set and intent action.

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing something about tightening restrictions on use of custom `Parcelable` objects in `AlarmManager` `Intent`s. I can't find the reference now. You should figure out a way to rearchitect your app so that you don't send a custom `Parcelable` to the `AlarmManager`.

You can serialize your custom `Parcelable` to a simple `String` or a `byte[]` and put that in the `Intent` and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Here's an example of how to do that: https://gist.github.com/jacklt/6711967 I haven't checked that code to see if it works, but you should get the basic idea.